# Change languages in app

Tags: android, android-xml

I have a android app that supports both English and French. I have a toggle button to switch between the two languages. I have 2 string.xml files with the same variable names but, obviously, the values are in separate languages.

An example:

English: `<string name="username">UserName</string>`

French: `<string name="username">Nom d'utilisateur</string>`

The file names are strings.xml(English). That is in the values folder under res. The other file is strings_fr.xml(French). That is under the values-fr folder under res.

Is there a way, once the user switches the toggle to have the files switch out?

I know of Locales but I found them to be buggy and slow.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "switches the toggle", do you mean switches a toggle inside your app or switches the toggle on android settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you tried with Locale so far, but this code will set the language until you set it back again or the app is restarted.

This should not come with any drawback in performance.

```
Configuration originalConfig = this.getResources().getConfiguration();
Locale locale = new Locale("fr"); //as an example
Configuration c = new Configuration();
c.locale = locale;
this.getResources().updateConfiguration(c,
            this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Where `this` is a subclass of Activity obviously.

Comment: Can I get this to change all my values right away? After I change the toggle I need everything to change including the tabbar.

Comment: No, only subsequent calls to getString will be affected. You would have to reload your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should rename "strings_fr.xml" in to "strings.xml"
And you will have 2 folders: "values" (default) and values-fr(for french localization). with files strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it with:

```
1) Put strings.xml file in values folder which is default.

2) create a strings.xml file in values-fr folder.
```